# Get unit and not base unit

Tags: pint

I am trying to get a more meaningful unit name when converting between unit systems.

In a separate file (custom_en.txt), I have defined a new unit system:

```
@system Nmm using international
    millimeter
    kilogram
    second
@end
```

I define a quantity of 1MPa:

```
import pint

UR = pint.UnitRegistry(system="SI", auto_reduce_dimensions=True)
UR.load_definitions("custom_en.txt")

q = 1.0 * UR.megapascal
```

I can express it in SI:

```
>>>UR.default_system = "SI"
>>>print("SI: " + str(q.to_base_units()))
SI: 1000000.0 kilogram / meter / second ** 2
```

in MKS:

```
>>>UR.default_system = "mks"
>>>print("mks: " + str(q.to_base_units()))
mks: 1000000.0 kilogram / meter / second ** 2
```

or in Nmm:

```
>>>UR.default_system = "Nmm"
>>>print("Nmm: " + str(q.to_base_units()))
Nmm: 1000.0 kilogram / millimeter / second ** 2
```

However, I would like to be able to represent them as:

```
SI: 1000000.0 pascal
mks: 1000000.0 pascal
Nmm: 1.0 megapascal
```

Do you know how can I achieve it?

Using pint: `0.22` on PYTHON: `3.9.18`